# Property [lesson_id] does not exist on this collection instance - EVEN THOUGH I'm using a foreach and therefore retrieving only 1 model

Tags: php, laravel, collections, properties

I've got a simple LessonUser table and model - 3 columns + timestamps.

I'm using Laravel 8 and doing TDD.

I grab some data from the table:

```
/** get the latest lessonUser for each lesson_id */
    $latestUserLessons =
        LessonUser::
            select('user_id', 'lesson_id', 'status_id')
            ->where('user_id', $user)
            ->latest()
            ->get()
            ->groupBy('lesson_id')
            ;
```

If I run this:

```
        foreach ($latestUserLessons as $latestUserLesson)
               {
                    dd($latestUserLesson);
               }
```

I get:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2731
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => App\Models\LessonUser {#2741
      #guarded: []
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "lesson_users"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:3 [
        "user_id" => 1
        "lesson_id" => 1
        "status_id" => 1
      ]
      #original: array:3 [
        "user_id" => 1
        "lesson_id" => 1
        "status_id" => 1
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
    }
  ]
}
```

So I clearly have the 'lesson_id' property.

But when I run this:

```
        foreach ($latestUserLessons as $latestUserLesson)
        {
            dd($latestUserLesson->lesson_id);
        }
```

I get the dreaded:

```
Property [lesson_id] does not exist on this collection instance.
  at C:\xampp\htdocs\tdd\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Traits\EnumeratesValues.php:850
    846▕      */
    847▕     public function __get($key)
    848▕     {
    849▕         if (! in_array($key, static::$proxies)) {
  ➜ 850▕             throw new Exception("Property [{$key}] does not exist on this collection instance.");
    851▕         }
    852▕
    853▕         return new HigherOrderCollectionProxy($this, $key);
    854▕     }
  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\tdd\app\Http\Controllers\SeshController.php:30
      Illuminate\Support\Collection::__get("lesson_id")
  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\tdd\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php:54
      App\Http\Controllers\SeshController::buildSesh()
  Tests:  1 failed
  Time:   1.17s
```

I understand I'll get this error if I try to get a property from a collection, but here I clearly have an instance of the model.
I've tried: using eloquent for the data retrieval; using a 'for' loop with increments, up to a count of the models retrieved, that control the array displacement etc etc and I just keep getting the same error.

Am I missing something?  Is there another way to get that field data?

Gagh!!  Help!!

Comment: You have a collection under `dd($latestUserLesson);`. Dump the dd($latestUserLesson**s**); and see what you have there. The $latestUserLesson (singular) must be a model not a collection

Comment: you grouped them with `groupBy`, so you have a collection of collections

Comment: `groupBy('lesson_id')` will result in a collection of collections so a single level of looping won't cut it

Comment: @Militaru - Yeah, I did that and it works fine - I get a collection of 2 instances of the model LessonUser with all the right data - each one clearly having 'lesson_id' as one of the properties.  And when I dd $latestUserLesson (singular) it is a model with 'lesson_id'.  That's why I'm stumped - I can't see why it's not working and I can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Look at your data dump again: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2731  #items: array:1 [` this is not a model instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a collection of collections. You have to iterate the collection and the collections that are nested in it to get the LessonUser models.

```
foreach ($latestUserLessons as $group) {
    foreach ($group as $latestUserLesson) {
        dd($latestUserLesson->lesson_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  The lesson to me here (along with the comment from @apokryfos) is to REALLY look at the output.  That does show that it's a collection of collections - hence nesting required.